# Angular Visualforce is freezing in IPad

Tags: salesforce1-app, angularjs, ipad

### Background

We have a simple VF page that is made using AngularJS+Bootstrap.

The page works perfect in browsers (Desktop, Mobile, Iphone and Android S1 app). 
There is not errors (javascript or apex), we've checked all consoles and debugging ways.

### Issue

However, randomly it freeze in S1 IPad App when we tap a `<button >`. 
It seams like a transparent layer is locking the entire screen. Or that all events (click tab scroll) are locked.

### Weirdness

If we change the orientation to landscape the screen is unlocked. If we turned again to portrait it lock again.

### Additional info

- This is the main tag: `<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Store_Visit__c"  extensions="StoreVisitController" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" docType="html-5.0">`
- We've added this: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0001, minimum-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, user-scalable=no"/>`
- To avoid gray screen we have this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kDtLIAU
- Also, followed this : https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC

### Question

**Is any way to debug the WebView that Salesforce1 uses for VF Pages?** I think that will help to see the console of that safari.

Any help out there?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something tells me this issue will be nigh impossible for any of us to resolve without reviewing your entire application. And, at the end of the day, it is likely to be a pure Javascript issue, meaning the question itself probably belongs on [so] even if it can be answered.

Comment: @AdrianLarson probably you are right. I hope Salesforce could help us to, at least, debug the issue.  Do you know how to debug the WebView that S1 uses for VF Pages?

Comment: so had same issue. What we did. when user focus on the input button using javascript we are just removing the complete text and they can enter the values. This is the way we tried to overcome this issue

Comment: I don't, and debugging angular is notoriously difficult. I would make sure you back up your project and then just fiddle with parameters and see if any of your changes isolate the problem. Or see if you can build a minimum viable reproduction from scratch.

Comment: @Ratan Sorry but I don't get what you mean. Let me check if I understood, When an input type button has focus, you are clearing the text value of other inputs? Do you have any link related to this issue ? Thanks

Comment: sorry man but I don't have any reference link for this issue. We proposed this solution to fix this issue.. check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xbeR2/

Comment: Thank you @Ratan, we have found the solution. I'll post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We've found the solution. I'm positing it in case other struggle the same issue.*

After opening a case, Salesforce told as that that was a known issue for them. It is caused by the version of `WkWebview` they are using. Technically, the render engine of that webView as problems with certain kind of `display:none/block` that are used by Angular or others JS Frameworks.

### The solution

Quite simple, just update to iOS 10 :)

Comment: ahh means Apple finally fixed this issue. great

Comment: Correct..... :)